# Como agregar datos de tabla html a textbox o textarea

Tags: javascript, mysql, jquery, jsp

Estimados tengo una duda, quisiera saber como puedo agregar datos capturados de una tabla html con javascript u jsp.
Mi idea es que cada vez que seleccione una fila de una tabla con un checkbox, se me agregue el valor de ese dato en un textbox o textarea, y se selecciono varios, todos se agreguen al textbox o textarea pero separados por comas ya que esos serian mis parametros para ejecutar una consulta sql.

Esta seria la tabla de donde capturo los datos

```
<div class="content container-fluid col-lg-10">
    <div class="left panel-default">
        <div class="title panel-heading">Seleccionar guías a mover</div>
        <div class="panel-body panel panel-primary">  
<table class="table table-hover table table-responsive col-sm-6" id="tabla1">
                   <tbody>
                   <tr id="a1">

                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Awb</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Origen</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Destino</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Piezas</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Kilos</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Volumen</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Id Vuelo</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Tramo</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Mover</th>

                   </tr>
<%

try


{
    for(int i=0; i<guia.size(); i++)
           {


                        out.println("<tr id='a2'>");
                        out.println("<td class='cantidad'><input type='text' name='txt_guia' class='cantidad' value='"+guia.get(i).getNumeroGuia()+"'></td>");

                        out.println("<td class='check'>"+guia.get(i).getOrigenGuia()+"</td>");
                        out.println("<td class='check'>"+guia.get(i).getDestinoGuia()+"</td>");
                        //out.println("<td>"+guia.get(i).getOrigenVueloReserva()+"</td>");

                        out.println("<td class='check'>"+guia.get(i).getPiezasGuia()+"</td>");
                        out.println("<td class='check'>"+guia.get(i).getKilosGuia()+"</td>");
                        out.println("<td class='check'>"+guia.get(i).getVolumenGuia()+"</td>");
                        out.println("<td class='check'>"+guia.get(i).getIdVueloGuia()+"</td>");
                        out.println("<td class='check'>"+guia.get(i).getIdTramoGuia()+"</td>");

                        out.println("<td><input type='checkbox' name='check_guia' class='form-control checkbox' value='"+guia.get(i).getNumeroGuia()+"'></td>");



           }     

}
catch(java.lang.NullPointerException ex)
{
    out.println("<p>'"+ex.getMessage()+"'</p>");
    out.println("</tr>");
}


%>
</tbody>
                </table>

        </div>
    </div>      
    </div>
```

aca la tabla que recibe las columnas seleccionadas
y abajo de la tabla está el textbox que deberia mostrar los datos

```
<div class="content container-fluid col-lg-10">
    <div class="right panel-default">
        <div class="title panel-heading">Guías Asignadas</div>
        <div class="panel-body panel panel-primary">    
<table class="table table-hover table table-responsive col-sm-6" id="tabla2">
                   <tbody>
                   <tr>

                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Awb</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Origen</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Destino</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Piezas</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Kilos</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Volumen</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Id Vuelo</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Tramo</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Acción</th>
                   </tr>

                </tbody>  
               </table>
            <input type="text" id="txt_mostrar" class="form-control">
<br><br><br><br>
```

```
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

aca el codigo de javascript que se encarga de capturar el dato seleccionado de la columna llamada "awb" de la tabla.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
        // el checkbox esta marcado
        // movemos la columna a la tabla2
        var tr=$(this).parents("tr").appendTo("#tabla2 tbody");
                    console.log($(this).parents('tr').find('td.cantidad').html());

                    var dato = $(this).parents('tr').find('input:text[name="txt_guia"]').val();
                    $('#txt_mostrar').val(dato);

    }else{
        // el checkbox esta desmarcado
        // movemos la columna a la tabla1
        var tr=$(this).parents("tr").appendTo("#tabla1 tbody");
    }


});
});

</script>
```

el problema es que al seleccionar el dato me lo captura, pero si selecciono otro, entonces me reemplaza el anterior en el campo de texto y lo que necesito es que cada valor capturado se muestre uno al lado del otro separado por coma.

aquí la imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de asignar el valor, debes de capturar el valor existente y concatenar el nuevo.  Algo asi:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
    {       

       var dato = $(this).parents('tr').find('input:text[name="txt_guia"]').val();
       var valor = $('#txt_mostrar').val();
       if (valor == '') {
          $('#txt_mostrar').val(dato);
       } else {
         $('#txt_mostrar').val(valor + ',' + dato);
       }

    }else{
        // el checkbox esta desmarcado
        // movemos la columna a la tabla1
        var tr=$(this).parents("tr").appendTo("#tabla1 tbody");
        $('#txt_mostrar').val("");
        var valor = '';
        $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(i, check) {
          if($(check).is(":checked")) {
            var dato = $(this).parents('tr').find('input:text[name="txt_guia"]').val();
            var valor = $('#txt_mostrar').val();
            if (valor == '') {
              $('#txt_mostrar').val(dato);
            } else {
              $('#txt_mostrar').val(valor + ',' + dato);
            }
          }
        });
    }

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="content container-fluid col-lg-10">
    <div class="right panel-default">
        <div class="title panel-heading">Guías Asignadas</div>
        <div class="panel-body panel panel-primary">    
<table class="table table-hover table table-responsive col-sm-6" id="tabla2">
                   <tbody>
                   <tr>

                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Awb</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Origen</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Destino</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Piezas</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Kilos</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Volumen</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Id Vuelo</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Tramo</th>
                       <th class="bg bg-primary">Acción</th>
                   </tr>
                   <tr id='a2'>
                        <td class='cantidad'><input type='text' name='txt_guia' class='cantidad' value='1'></td>

                        <td class='check'></td>
                        <td class='check'></td>
                        <td></td>

                        <td class='check'></td>
                        <td class='check'></td>
                        <td class='check'></td>
                        <td class='check'></td>
                       <td class='check'></td>

                        <td><input type='checkbox' name='check_guia' class='form-control checkbox' value='1'></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id='a2'>");
                        <td class='cantidad'><input type='text' name='txt_guia' class='cantidad' value='2'></td>");

                        <td class='check'></td>
                        <td class='check'></td>
                        <td></td>

                        <td class='check'></td>
                        <td class='check'></td>
                        <td class='check'></td>
                        <td class='check'></td>
                       <td class='check'></td>

                        <td><input type='checkbox' name='check_guia' class='form-control checkbox' value='2'></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>  
               </table>
            <input type="text" id="txt_mostrar" class="form-control">
<br><br><br><br>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: gracias amigo , pero lo único que ahora no me funciona la función que pasa la columna de la tabla de arriba a la de abajo :p

Comment: ya amigo gracias lo resolvi lo de la columna que no pasaba para abajo

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: De nada @SimónPereiraVigouroux solo una cosa, veo que has hecho varias preguntas pero no has aceptado ninguna respuesta.  Es una buena practica aceptar las respuestas que te han ayudado para que la comunidad te siga apoyando.  Saludos.

Comment: si es que soy nuevo en stackoverflow no tengo mucho tiempo usando esta app y tendría que ver en donde se aceptan

Comment: Es un checkmark que esta al lado izquierdo de la respuesta

Comment: Ahí si gracias.

Comment: una ultima consulta, si los datos que quiero mostrar son de tipo String y quiero que estos se visualicen separados por comas tal como me ayudaste, pero que los capture por ejemplo:'045-34323323','045-21343434' hay que agregar algo al codigo?

Comment: No, seria igual, pruebalo en mi respuesta

Comment: lo probé y solo me ejecuta la consulta si el campo de texto tiene un solo dato, pero si tiene mas de un dato, el sistema me dice que actualizó con éxito pero no actualiza los registros.

Comment: Eso es seguramente problema en el backend, o sea en el servidor.  No tiene nada que ver con el codigo de mi respuesta.  Asegurate que los campos en tu tabla tengan el tipo correcto.

Comment: Podría ser que al ser String esten entrando juntos ? ya que deberian entrar algo ahí '045-1234567','045-4522344', y alomejor están entrando juntos es decir algo así '045-1234567,045-4522344' como si fuese solo un String y podría ser eso?

Comment: Tendria que ver como guardas la informacion.

Comment: hice un System.out.Println   y mu muestra la info así                   
Información:   Conexion exitosa :)
Información:   las guias estan llegando como :145-89542389,145-78236734,549-123465432
podria ser ese el problema? igual agregare mas detalle

Comment: Ya resolvi el problema solo habia que agregar "" en el codigo de javascript valor + "','" + dato y así el dato pasa correctamente al servlet.

Comment: gracias igual por tu ayuda.